# React js Redirect Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using firebase auth for my React js project. **Aim** - When the user goes to the path -  '/home' , it should check whether the user is logged in or not. If not logged in, redirect to the path - '/'  ,or else render the component "Home". But, when I run the code, the ***functions*** are working properly but, the component is not rendering on the screen.

Code of App.js -

```
function App() {
var users;

  function checkUserLoggedIn() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
      users = user;
      console.log(users);
      users ? <Home /> : <Redirect to="/" />;
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Welcome />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/home">{checkUserLoggedIn()}</Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any idea why this is not working ?
Thanks !

Comment: In React the render function is 100% synchronous, so renderable JSX can't be returned in an asynchronous callback. You also don't return anything from `checkUserLoggedIn` or the firebase callback.

Comment: Thanks ! Is there any other method for this to achieve ?

Comment: Normally you would abstract the auth check/condition into a protected route component that either renders the component you want or it bounces you out. Check the [auth workflow](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow) example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a Dictionary file route
and add three files

- index.js
- publicRoute.js
- privateRoute.js

in index.js

```
/// index.js

import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import PrivateRoutes from './PrivateRoutes'
import PublicRoutes from './PublicRoutes';

function Routes() {
    const { pathname } = useLocation();
    const[isUserLoggedIn, setLoggedIn] = React.useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
      users = user;
      if(users){
        setLoggedIn(true)
        }
    }, [pathname]);
    

    return isUserLoggedIn ? <PrivateRoutes /> : <PublicRoutes />;

   

}

export default Routes;
```

And in publicRoutes.js

```
// publicRoute.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { HashRouter, Redirect, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const loading = (
  <div className="pt-3 text-center">
    <div className="sk-spinner sk-spinner-pulse"></div>
  </div>
)


// Pages
const Login = React.lazy(() => import('../views/pages/login/Login'));
const Register = React.lazy(() => import('../views/pages/register/Register'));


class PublicRoutes extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <HashRouter>
          <React.Suspense fallback={loading}>
            <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/register" name="Register Page" render={props => <Register {...props}/>} />
            <Route path="/login" name="Login Page" render={props => <Login {...props}/>} />
            <Route exact path="/register" name="Register Page" render={props => <Register {...props}/>} />
            <Redirect to='/login' />
            </Switch>
          </React.Suspense>
      </HashRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default PublicRoutes;
```

In Private Route

```
/// privateRoute.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { HashRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../scss/style.scss';

const loading = (
  <div className="pt-3 text-center">
    <div className="sk-spinner sk-spinner-pulse"></div>
  </div>
)

// Containers
const TheLayout = React.lazy(() => import('../containers/TheLayout'));

// Pages
const Page404 = React.lazy(() => import('../views/pages/page404/Page404'));
const Page500 = React.lazy(() => import('../views/pages/page500/Page500'));

class PrivateRoutes extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <HashRouter>
          <React.Suspense fallback={loading}>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/404" name="Page 404" render={props => <Page404 {...props}/>} />
              <Route exact path="/500" name="Page 500" render={props => <Page500 {...props}/>} />
              <Route path="/" name="Home" render={props => <TheLayout {...props}/>} />
            </Switch>
          </React.Suspense>
      </HashRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default PrivateRoutes;
```